# How to avoid sql injection in php?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

As questioned above how can I prevent sql injection by third party if my query for JQuery autocomplete using ajax.

[image]

Ajax call:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT  patient_name FROM patient where patient_sex like '%Female%' and patient_name LIKE  '%".strtoupper($len)."%'");   
$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($data, $row['patient_name']);    
}   
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: use prepared statements instead of mysql_query

Comment: [If you look at the right side of your web page you'll get first link to it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?lq=1)